# I would like to separate with split method and map an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, mapping

hello I would like a help on how I can separate an array with split that has an object that has its properties that has a name, course1, course2 and course3 that is empty. the courses that have text and that are in their content with sign + separate them in an array with the split property, and then encapsulate in an object array called courses and put to each course object its course identifier, credit and note, finally show it as object the original array.

Please help me, thank you.

Here I was doing the code but it doesn't work for me

```js
//this is my array
var alumno: [
          {
          'name' : 'ivan hambi apaza',
          'course1' : 'HISTORIA DE LA DANZA+2+16',
          'course2' : 'HISTORIA+3+17',
          'course3' : '',
          }
],
       
//a step that I was doing but it does not come out
alumnoN(){
var newArr = [...this.alumno]
              newArr.map(el => {
              return el.course1 = el.course1.split('+')
              })
              newArr.map(el => {
              return el.course2 = el.course2.split('+')
              })
              newArr.map(el => {
              return el.course3 = el.course3.split('+')
              })
              
    return newArr
}

  
console.log(alumnoN())
```

I would like as a result an object like this:

```
[
  {
      'name':'ivan hambi apaza',
      'courses':[
               {'course':'HISTORIA DE LA DANZA','credit':2,'note':16},
               {'course':'HISTORIA','credit':3,'note': 17},
              ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Your current syntax is not valid, you may wish to at least fix that first

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work for your requirement .

```js
function splitAlumno(alumno) {
        let finalList = [];
        for(let i=0;i<alumno.length;i++) {
            let object = alumno[i];
            let formattedObject = {
                name : object.name,
                courses : []
            };
            delete object.name;
            Object.keys(object).forEach(v => {
          if(object[v].trim().length === 0) return;
                let data = object[v].split('+');
                let course = {
                    course: data[0],
                    credit: data[1] ? data[1] : "",
                    note: data[2] ? data[2] : ""
                };
                formattedObject.courses.push(course);
            });
            finalList.push(formattedObject);
        }
        return finalList;
    }

    let alumno = [
            {
              'name' : 'ivan hambi apaza',
              'course1' : 'HISTORIA DE LA DANZA+2+16',
              'course2' : 'HISTORIA+3+17',
              'course3' : '',
            }
    ];

    console.log(splitAlumno(alumno));
```

Comment: consider removing the empty `course3` from the result (as shown in the OP expected result)

Comment: Great friend thank you very much I hope to help you with something

Answer (score 1):

Have a try this code. Using some nice ES6 features (destructuring, object property-value shorthand):

```js
// 'HISTORIA DE LA DANZA+2+16' => {'course':'HISTORIA DE LA DANZA','credit':2,'note':16}
function c2c(c) {
   if (c.length === 0) return null
   var [course,credit,note] = c.split("+")
   return {course,credit,note}
}

// {name:...,course1:...,course2:...,...} => ['HISTORIA DE LA DANZA+2+16',...]
function o2cs(o) {
   // return [o.course1,o.course2,o.course3] // sufficient ???
   var ret = []
   for (var k in o) {
      if (k.startsWith("course")) ret.push(o[k])
   }
   return ret
}

// main object conversion function
function a2a(o) {
   var courses = o2cs(o) // extract courses from o
   courses = courses.map(c2c) // convert strings to objects
   courses = courses.filter(Boolean) // filter non-null courses
   return {name: o.name, courses: courses}
}

// main function, just maps the array
function alumnoN(alumno) { return alumno.map(a2a) }


// test
var alumno = [
   {
      'name' : 'ivan hambi apaza',
      'course1' : 'HISTORIA DE LA DANZA+2+16',
      'course2' : 'HISTORIA+3+17',
      'course3' : '',
   },
]
console.log(alumnoN(alumno))
console.log(alumnoN(alumno)[0].courses)
```

Comment: Great friend thank you very much I hope to help you with something

Answer (score 1):

You could use `flatMap` and `reduce` and a custom function to return the course objects

```js
var alumno = [ { name: "ivan hambi apaza", course1: "HISTORIA DE LA DANZA+2+16", course2: "HISTORIA+3+17", course3: "", } ];

getspliob = (course) =>
  /\+/g.test(course)  // test if course includes + 
    ? ((ob = course.split("+")),  // split and get the array 
      { course: ob[0], credit: ob[1] || "0", note: ob[2] || "0" }) // build object
    : { course: course, credit: 0, note: 0 }; // else return default object

res = alumno.flatMap(({ name, course1, course2, course3 }) => //map the alumno array
  Object.values(
    [course1, course2, course3].reduce( // use reduce on courses 
      (r, o) => (
        o != ""             // check if  course is not empty string
          ? !r[name]    // check if object doesn't exist in accumulator r
            ? (r[name] = { ...r[name], name: name, courses: [getspliob(o)] }) // then build object 
            : r[name].courses.push(getspliob(o)) // else push to the already existing courses array 
          : r,
        r    // return accumulator 
      ),
      {}
    )
  )
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Great friend thank you very much I hope to help you with something

Comment: You're welcome :) if you find my answer helpful please consider giving it an upvote and mark it as accepted